# IE7 displays some cell contents from a table when that row is overflowed

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have the weirdest issue that I haven't been able to find a solution for. I have a table where one of the cells has its contents wrapped in a relatively positioned div element (essentially I'm showing a "progress bar" in a cell, so its a div with another div inside (that expands its width to the % completed), and a span inside that showing the value).

The table is inside a div that has its overflow-y set to auto, and a max-height of 400px.

In FF, Chrome, and IE8 and 9 it looks/works great, but in IE7, the cells with those progress bar divs continue to show their content and don't ever scroll with the rest of the table contents.

This JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ujV4M/1/ shows what I'm talking about if you view it in IE7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited: Add position:relative to the element containing the table

I removed the relative position, as I've known IE7 to cause issues with scrollable content areas with regards to elements that aren't statically positioned, and I added margin-left to the text:

http://jsfiddle.net/3H6eG/

Obviously my solution avoids the issue rather than solves it, but it looks like it works as it should. Or do you need relative positioning for a specific reason?

Adam

Comment: for that particular element it works, but I also have elements which require relative positioning because they include absolutely positioned things (basically a menu that has to be aligned a certain way)

Comment: Ah ok, in which case add position:relative to your div#pdtc, that ought to make the entire table behave